# Datatable.net table behaving oddly when pulling data from AWS API Gateway

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on an angular project where I'm trying to use a datatable from datatables.net to populate data I pulled from AWS via the API Gateway. If I use a regular table, the data displays just fine. When I initialize the datatable, the data still populates but the table is acting like there's no data. There's a message at the bottom that states, No data available in table. When I sort a column or search the data disappears. I suspect I'm not waiting long enough to initialize the table or perhaps I should be pulling it differently. Any help anyone can give would be greatly appreciated!!!

Here is my typescript code:

```
export class WasteComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {
    public tableData1: TableData;
    public dataTable: DataTable;
    enabled: number;
    wastename: string;
    ohdept: string;
    cadept: string;
    trgroup: string;
    bgroup: string;
    unid: string;
    psn: string;
    hazclass: string;
    pg: string;
    moe: string;
    ohio: number;
    trail: number;

    checkBoxValue(value){
        if (value == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        var data = [];
        var JSONService = "api gateway url";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: JSONService,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                for (var r = 0; r < response.Items.length; r++){
                    data.push([]);
                }
                for (var i = 0, len = response.Items.length; i < len; ++i) {
                    var row = i+1;
                    var enabled = response.Items[i].Enabled.N;
                    var wastename = response.Items[i].WasteName.S;
                    var ohdept = response.Items[i].OHDept.S;
                    var cadept =  response.Items[i].CADept.S;
                    var trgroup = response.Items[i].TRGroup.S;
                    var bgroup = response.Items[i].BGroup.S;
                    var unid = response.Items[i].UNID.S;
                    var psn = response.Items[i].PSN.S;
                    var hazclass = response.Items[i].HazClass.S;
                    var pg = response.Items[i].PG.S;
                    var moe = response.Items[i].MOE.S;
                    var ohio = response.Items[i].Ohio.N;
                    var trail = response.Items[i].Trail.N;
                    var uid = response.Items[i].UID.S;
                    data[i].push(row, !!enabled, wastename, ohdept, cadept, trgroup, bgroup, unid, psn, hazclass, pg, moe, ohio, trail, uid);
                }


                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }) 

        this.tableData1 = {
            headerRow: ['', 'Enabled', 'Waste', 'OH Dept', 'CA Dept', 'TR Group', 'BGB Group', 'UNID', 'PSN', 'Haz Class', 'PG', 'MOE', 'Ohio', 'Trail', 'Edit'],
            dataRows: data
        }

        this.dataTable = {
            headerRow: ['', 'Enabled', 'Waste', 'OH Dept', 'CA Dept', 'TR Group', 'BGB Group', 'UNID', 'PSN', 'Haz Class', 'PG', 'MOE', 'Ohio', 'Trail', 'Edit'],
            dataRows: data
        };
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $('#datatables').DataTable({
            "deferRender": true,
            "lengthMenu": [
              [10, 25, 50, -1],
              [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
            responsive: true,
            language: {
              search: "_INPUT_",
              searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
            }
          });

          $('.card .material-datatables label').addClass('form-group');
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {

    }

    createDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCreateWaste, {
            width: '500px',
            data: {enabled:1}
        });
    }

    updateDialog(uid, enabled, wastename, ohdept, cadept, trgroup, bgroup, unid, psn, hazclass, pg, moe, ohio, trail): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCreateWaste, {
            width: '500px',
            data: {
                enabled: this.checkBoxValue(enabled),
                wastename: wastename,
                ohdept: ohdept,
                cadept: cadept,
                trgroup: trgroup,
                bgroup: bgroup,
                unid: unid,
                psn: psn,
                hazclass: hazclass,
                pg: pg,
                moe: moe,
                ohio: this.checkBoxValue(ohio),
                trail: this.checkBoxValue(trail),
                uid: uid
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="toolbar">
                        <!--        Here you can write extra buttons/actions for the toolbar              -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="material-datatables">
                      <table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">{{ dataTable.headerRow[0] }}</th>
                                  <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">{{ dataTable.headerRow[1] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[2] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[3] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[4] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[5] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[6] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[7] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[8] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[9] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[10] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[11] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[12] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[13] }}</th>
                                  <th>{{ dataTable.headerRow[14] }}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let row of dataTable.dataRows">
                                    <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[5]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[6]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[7]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[8]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[9]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[10]}}</td>
                                    <td>{{row[11]}}</td>
                                    <td *ngIf="row[12] == 1"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                    <td *ngIf="row[12] == 0"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                    <td *ngIf="row[13] == 1"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                    <td *ngIf="row[13] == 0"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                                    <td class="td-actions text-left">
                                      <button mat-raised-button type="button" class="btn btn-success {{row[14]}}" (click)="updateDialog(row[14],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13])">
                                        <i class="material-icons">edit</i>
                                      </button>
                                    </td> 
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

[image: Datatable acting oddly]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this a different way. The data is coming in now but I'm having issues getting sorting and filtering to work.

```
export class WasteComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {

    checkBoxValue(value){

        if (value == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    displayedColumns: string[] = ['enabled', 'wastename', 'ohdept', 'cadept', 'trgroup', 'bgroup', 'unid', 'psn', 'hazclass', 'pg', 'moe', 'ohio', 'trail', 'edit'];
    dataSource: any;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private chRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public dialog: MatDialog, private wasteService: WasteService) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        this.wasteService.getAllWastes().subscribe(data => {

            this.chRef.detectChanges(); 

            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(Object.values(data)[1]);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;    
        });
    }

    applyFilter(event: Event) {

        const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
        console.log(filterValue);
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }

    getWastes() {

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {

    }

    createDialog(): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCreateWaste, {
            width: '500px',
            data: {enabled:1}
        });
    }

    updateDialog(uid, enabled, wastename, ohdept, cadept, trgroup, bgroup, unid, psn, hazclass, pg, moe, ohio, trail): void {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCreateWaste, {
            width: '500px',
            data: {
                enabled: this.checkBoxValue(enabled),
                wastename: wastename,
                ohdept: ohdept,
                cadept: cadept,
                trgroup: trgroup,
                bgroup: bgroup,
                unid: unid,
                psn: psn,
                hazclass: hazclass,
                pg: pg,
                moe: moe,
                ohio: this.checkBoxValue(ohio),
                trail: this.checkBoxValue(trail),
                uid: uid
            }
        });
    }
}
```